# Compulsory to use Windows Server 2012?

Tags: development, windows-server, development-enviroment

Problem:
Do you need to have a lot of knowledge in Windows server 2012 when you are a SP developer?

Answer (score 1):

bit of a vauge question! also like to note that your asking two questions that are subjects on their own

to put it into context, I have a virtual machine that runs a server hosting sharepoint. When developing you need working knowledge of visual studio to obviously programme in! but when it comes to debugging the code because of an error reported on a sharepoint page than you would need to know where to look.

so to the point you need to know about dns(to an extent) and/or host files.

you need to know of the following applications:

central admin

IIS manager

eventviewer / uls

SQL server

active directory

services

group policy manager

above apps found in admin tools within the start menu

windows shell managment (powershell)

where shepoint physical files are stored, where the web apps are stored

where the strongly named dlls are stored (assembly folder)

im sure iv missed a few but those to me as a developer are most important! maybe youll use some on daily basis like VS, central admin, iis and poweshell

but it also comes down to how much access the devloper has! in development on my vpc everything is on one server but when it comes to deployment on live you would have a server for sharepoint, server for SQL database and server for AD.

You possible wouldnt have access to most or any or you would have access to all! learning about the server is like riding a bike, the more you use it the more you know how it works and where everything fits making the ride easier. It just takes time just like learning how to use a new operating system.

**to answer your questions:**

> Compulsory to use Windows Server 2012?

no you dont, depending on what version of sharepoint your running ;)

> Do you need to have a lot of knowledge in Windows server 2012 when you
>   are a SP developer?

to start yes and no. yes becasue when you come into issues that are complex like code being righ but the setup is wrong than you would need some indepth knowledge, no because you could develop a webpart easily without much knowledge of the server! so it depends on the situation!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need in-depth knowledge of Windows Server 2012 per se but certain elements of it are required of it for SharePoint development - Active Directory, IIS, Security Authentication, etc. In addition, PowerShell and some working knowledge of SQL Server (DBA functions) can be helpful. Here are a few links to the Microsoft sites that can be useful for the beginning SharePoint developer -

[SharePoint developer training](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905692)

[SharePoint 2013 development overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sharepoint/jj164084%28v=office.15%29)